# quartz composer view output: How can I get immediately the new values of outputs, if they change?

Tags: cocoa, xcode, quartz-composer

I created a cocoa program with a quartz composer view. I can get the output values with:

```
[qcView valueForOutputKey:@"Output"]
```

But how can I get immediately the new values of outputs, if they change?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using Key-Value Observing, your class can be sent a message automatically when the value changes.

For a `QCView`, you need to connect a `QCPatchController` instance (which is a layer that adds KVO compliance) --- see http://developer.apple.com/mac/library/technotes/tn2005/tn2146.html for details.